# Email verification not working in codeigniter getting error Not Found

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm  trying to send a verification link through email to activate registered account.I'm successfully receiving the mail but when i click on the received link i'm getting error NOT FOUND.

**code for sending email is below**

```
public function send_email($title,$fname,$lname,$email,$code)
{
    $from_email = "pavan@domain.com";
    $to_email = $this->input->post('email'); 
    $this->load->library('email'); 
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");

    $this->email->from($from_email, 'Industry Speak'); 
    $this->email->to($email);
    $this->email->subject('Registration Confirmation Mail from Industry Speak'); 

    $message =  '</<!DOCTYPE html>
                     <html>
                     <head>
                        <title></title>
                     </head>
                     <body>
                        <p>Welcome to Industry Speak <b>'.$title.' '.$fname.' '.$lname.'</b>, </p>
                        <br>
                        <p>Thanks for the signing up!</p>
                        <P>Your account has been created, you can login with your provided credentials after you have activated your account by pressing the url below. </p>                    
                        <p>Please click this link to activate your account: </p>
                        <a href='.base_url().'Home/email_verify/'.$code.'/'.$email.'>Click Here to Activate Your Account</a>   


                     </body>
                     </html>';
        $this->email->message($message); 

        if($this->email->send()) 
        {
           $this->session->set_flashdata("msg", "<div class='alert alert-error' style='background: rgba(22, 111, 24, 0.84); color: #fff;'>
                    <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                    <strong>Sucess..!</strong> We sent a activation link to " .$email. " Please Activate your account. 
                </div>");   
            redirect('Home/clients');
        }
    }
```

code of my controller **email_verify** code is below

```
function email_verify($code,$email)
    {
        $condition=array("token_code"=>md5($code),"email_id"=>$email,"client_status"=>0);
                    $email_verification=$this->data['email_veri']=$this->Frontend_model->verify_email($condition);

        if ($email_verification>0)
        {
             $this->session->set_flashdata("msg", "<div class='alert alert-error' style='background: rgba(22, 111, 24, 0.84); color: #fff;'>
                <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                <strong>Sucess..!</strong>Your account registered with " .$email. " is succesfully activated. Please login to your account. 
            </div>");   
            redirect('Home/clients');
        }
        else
        {
             $this->session->set_flashdata("msg", "<div class='alert alert-error' style='background: rgba(255, 87, 34, 0.96); color: #fff;'>
                <button class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
                <strong>Error..!</strong> Getting error in activating your account linked with " .$email. " Please try again. 
            </div>");   
            redirect('Home/clients');
        }       

    }
```

**Error when i click on received link in mail**

[image]

please help me where i done wrong and please help to resolve this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Um, it's annoying to state the obvious but *your url must be wrong.* The image says you are requesting /Industry/Speak/10-01-2017/Home/email_verify/abcdewhatever/address@example.com -- have you compared this to the urls you use to successfully access your site?

Answer (score 0):

You defined your uri as `verify/(:any)` but you're trying to access `email_verify/`.

[Look at the docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#wildcards):

```
$route['product/:num'] = 'catalog/product_lookup';
```

> In a route, the array key contains the URI to be matched, while the
>   array value contains the destination it should be re-routed to. In the
>   above example, if the literal word “product” is found in the first
>   segment of the URL, and a number is found in the second segment, the
>   “catalog” class and the “product_lookup” method are instead used.